# Is there an R function to find the probability of certain data being created from a Beta distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution, probability-density

I have a vector **x** of values in R. I want to know the probability that the data was made from a Beta(20,40) distribution. I am using R.

When I make this function call

```
dbeta(x, 10, 20)
```

I get the probability for each entry in the vector.

```
0.065278039 0.003434240 0.036265577 0.175467370 0.018132789 0.065278039
0.175467370 0.175467370
```

I was wondering if it is possible to output one number to show the probability that the entire data vector was made from a Beta distribution.

- For example, the probability of dataset $x$ being generated from a Beta(20,40) distribution is *some number*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by performing some hypotesis tests like Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Hoeffing and compare the data taken from the dataset with the Beta(20,40).

This tests are used to evaluate the hypothesis that two samples are drawn for the same distribution.

Something like this `ks.test(x,y = 'pbeta', shape1 = 20, shape2 = 40)` should do the work.